# Can DjangoRestFramework accept JWTs that have more than username/password in payload?

Tags: ember.js, django-rest-framework, jwt, auth0

I have a Django application that uses the Django Rest Framework. At first I was just using Session, and Token authentication, but now want to implement JWT Token authentication. I downloaded a package called djangorestframework-jwt that allows you to use JWT for authentication in DRF. The crux of the problem is that my client side application is using Auth0 which can return a lot of different information, first name, last name, userid, etc. We are using Auth0 with gmail as an identity provider to log into our client side EmberJS application. For our data adapters to get data from Django though, we are using 1 consistent token that we configured in our Auth0 account that is tied to a user in Django. What I would like to accomplish is to use the JWT returned from Auth0, instead of this 1 token, to authenticate all our requests to Django. Can you authenticate yourself in Django without using a Django User object?